# jQuery UI Datepicker not working in Unsemantic Responsive Grid-Container

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, grid, datepicker

I'm using Unsemantic for an assignment and need to have a datepicker to set appointments. So far I have been through quite a bit of troubleshooting and trying to find the issues in my code that have prevented me from being able to use the datepicker in my site when it works fine when I set up a dummy page with the same jQuery code. 
So now I have my page setup but I have two datepickers - one inside the main grid-container and one outside. The datepicker that I have set up outside the grid-container div works fine, but when I have one inside, it just doesn't work and is a simple textbox. My code is below (I've excluded a few elements to make it clearer):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
      <div class="grid-container">
      <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    </div>
<!--<script src="./assets/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>-->
<script src="./assets/javascripts/demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason why jquery.js is commented out is because for some reason it stops the datepicker from working even when the datepicker is outside the grid-container.
This is all in unsemantic so I am using Unsemantic's js and css files with no alterations to their grid-container code, and there is nothing in the css file that I can see that would void the jQuery once inside the grid container.
If anyone can tell me why/how the datepicker doesn't work inside the grid-container or whether there is some extra issue with the jquery.js that needs to be resolved, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the id "datepicker" twice in the same page. I change the 2nd one to "datepicker2" and added another entry in the jQuery function and it works.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();    
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

And then...

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked immediately! Thank you so much!